# Custom validators in MVC 4

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have recently upgraded my MVC 3 project to MVC 4. After all the edits I got stuck at problem with validators, because my old validators inherit and use the class ModelClientValidationRule, which apparently doesn't exist in System.Web.WebPages v2. But due to some other stuff in project, I can't reference to v1 and frankly I don't even want to. Does anyone came across with this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModelClientValidationRule` class does exist inside the `System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0` assembly and it is forwarded from the `System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0` assembly where it previously resided:

[image]

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 RC.